# Is it possible to use a local TCP/IP connection as a subsitute for standard I/O between two scripts?

Tags: javascript, sockets, tcp, extendscript

Pardon my networking ignorance, but here's my problem:

I have a JavaScript document automation environment (Adobe ExtendScript) which is isolated from the rest of my system. I want basic I/O capabilities between any script running in ExtendScript and any other program I want (ruby scripts, mysql... etc). One object available to me in ExtendScript is a Socket object which can "create a TCP/IP connection or establish a TCP/IP server". Could setting up a TCP/IP server and connecting to it from outside effectively emulate the I/O capabilities that I'm looking for? Because I'm running everything locally does that effectively eliminate the network latency that you would normally expect from such a connection? Is there a catch to this that I'm not aware of?

Comment: That's an interesting problem. I think this might work.
Check out http://extendables.org/docs/packages/http/doc/readme.html for easier HTTP handling.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the use of sockets. But if you're just looking for inter-process communication, it might be simpler to use [named pipes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe). JSX's File object lets you read & write arbitrary files -- it should be able to work with a named pipe.